# Sequelize - Map model to fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sequelize.js

Im making two models: Article and User, and the Article model contains Author and Editor fields, that must contain links to items in User table. How do I map that, so the field contains two lookups to the User table in those fields?

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Article = sequelize.define('Article', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    html: DataTypes.STRING,
    author: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    editor: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    deletedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {});

  Article.associate = function(models) {
  };

  return Article;
};
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password_hash: DataTypes.STRING,
    role: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    deletedAt: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});

  User.associate = function(models) {
  };

  return User;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create associations between the two models.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Article = sequelize.define('Article', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    html: DataTypes.STRING,
    author: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    editor: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    deletedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {});

  Article.associate = function(models) {
    Article.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'article_id' });
  };

  return Article;
};
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password_hash: DataTypes.STRING,
    role: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    deletedAt: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});

  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Articles, { foreignKey: 'user_id'})
  };

  return User;
};
```

to query Articles with User you have to include the User in the query.

```
Article.findAll({
include: [User],
});

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I assosiate different users to the "Author" and "Editor" fields?